# importing urllib.parse does not work in Visual Studio Code

Tags: urllib

In Visual Studio Code I am trying to import urllib.parse as described in docs.python.org, but nothing I do  works.

This works in python terminal:
import urllib
import parse from urllib

In Visual Studio Code:
import urllib
import parse from urllib

produces:
ImportError: cannot import name parse

Any ideas why this doesn't work in VSC?